# Element move smoothly between activities/fragments

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to remake this animation in which elements move smoothly between contexts on swipe event

I know about Shared Element Transition but I think it's not. Below is a detail gif

> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSK6I.jpg)

What is this animation ?

Comment: this library is not the same but I think this is helpful for you:https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: This just looks like a combination of a shared element transition and a excessive fragment transition, have a look into https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate